# mysql update row with value from another row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not particularly new to mysql, but I'm new to updating very large tables.
I can do this while using two queries, but I'm attempting to make the process faster because I'm going to end up doing this for millions of rows.
I've been trying to update a table, based on another row in the same table. The table I have looks something like:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTxIk.png)

Basically what I'd like to do is update the 'prev_num_dialed' field with the 'dialed_num' field of the same 'callid', but from the previous 'segment'.

so the first line callid '1', segment '1', would not update 'prev_num_dialed' because there's no previous segment. 
However the second line callid '1', segment '2', would update 'prev_num_dialed' to '1234567' because that's what the previous segments number was.

My current attempt looks like the following:

```
$query = "UPDATE " . $table_name . " as t1 
SET t1.prev_num_dialed = (
SELECT dialed_num, callid
FROM (SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . ") as t2
WHERE t2.segment = t1.segment - 1)
AND t2.callid = t1.callid
";
```

but this is not working as I'd like it to, it's updating from its own row. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: *this is not working* means ?

Comment: It would also help if you put the query in the question *after* variable substitution -- especially because I don't think the query is syntactically correct.

Comment: Sorry, the above version is giving an error. my first attempt was updating the rows, but was updating from the same 'segment'. The current version is saying "operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: correct, I'm new to this kind of syntax. I know what I'd like to do, but I'm unsure of how to execute it syntactically.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply suggest:

```
UPDATE $table_name t1 JOIN
       $table_name t2
       ON t2.callid = t1.callid AND
          t2.segment = t1.segment - 1
    SET t1.prev_num_dialed = t2.dialed_num;
```

I think this does what you intend.  This does *not* set the column value to `NULL` if there is no match.  You can do that with a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`.

Comment: this updates from it's own column. I need it to update from the previous segments column.

Comment: ah, there was just a typo, but looks like you fixed it. this works perfectly. thank you